# Do we need to differntiate anything for this in IE8?

Tags: jquery, cross-browser

I have this code in my application

```
  var checked = $('#fieldset input[type=checkbox]:checked');
                    var ids= checked.map(function() {
                        return $(this).val();
                    }).get().join(',');
```

in firefox I am getting all the checked Ids something like this.. 
123,234,443..
but same code in IE8 its showing only first Id not all checked id's even its checked?

Even if I uncheck the first checkbox if I check second checkbox second checkbox value showing as null?

can anybody help me out?
thanks

Comment: side note: instead of `input[type=checkbox]` you can just write `:checkbox`

Comment: Your code (as it is) runs fine for me in IE8. Some invalid HTML markup perhaps?

Comment: @patrick: `$(this).val()` returnes the `id` of a checkbox for you?

Comment: so is that somethign problem with my HTML?

Comment: @jAndy - No. OP labeled the variable "IDs", but that doesn't mean he's talking about the ID of the checkbox. He is getting the `.val()` of the checkbox, and he mentioned that it works properly in Firefox.

Comment: @kumar - I don't know. I'm just saying that the code you provided works for me in IE8. I can't see your HTML from here. It's just a possibility.

Comment: @kumar - Are you trying to get the "value" of the checkbox, or its "ID" attribute?

Comment: Yes $(this).val() return all the Id's of checkbox for me.. in firefox but in IE8 it returning allways first id other id's it showing me null..

Comment: I assigned my chekcbox somethign like this Patrick,,

<input type="checkbox" name="chk" value="<%Model.StudentID%>"/>
so each and Everytime the Id is dynamically generating for this checkbkox

Comment: @kumar - Your code works for me in IE8. Test it here: http://jsfiddle.net/99j23/ If there is an error in your HTML markup, it may cause problems for IE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
var checked = $('#fieldset').find('input:checkbox:checked');

var ids     = checked.map(function() {
    return this.id;
}).get().join(',');
```